# WM_TIMER gets lost in specific conditions

Tags: c, winapi

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

class tWnd {
private:
    static LRESULT CALLBACK Disp_test_WndProc(
        HWND hwnd,        // handle to window
        UINT uMsg,        // message identifier
        WPARAM wParam,    // first message parameter
        LPARAM lParam)    // second message parameter
    {
        switch (uMsg) 
        {
            case WM_TIMER:{
                printf("timer\n");

                return 0;
            }

            case WM_PAINT: 
                // Paint the window's client area. 
                return 0; 

            case WM_DESTROY: 
                return 0; 

            case WM_HOTKEY:{

            } return 0;
            // 
            // Process other messages. 
            // 
            default: 
                return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam); 
        } 
        return 0; 
    }

public:     
    tWnd() {

            WNDCLASSA wc;
            wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW; 
            wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC) Disp_test_WndProc; 
            wc.cbClsExtra = 0; 
            wc.cbWndExtra = 0; 
            wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL); 
            wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION); 
            wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW); 
            wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) NULL; 
            wc.lpszMenuName =  ""; 
            wc.lpszClassName = "Test"; 

            if (!RegisterClass(&wc)) 
               return; //cannot register window class



        HWND testingWindow = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST,"Test","topmost",WS_VISIBLE,0,0,200,200,0,0,0,0);

        SetTimer(testingWindow,101,500,(TIMERPROC)NULL);

        MSG recent;
        BOOL result;
        while((result=GetMessage(&recent,testingWindow,0,0))&&result!=-1) { //bool can be -1 in MS world
            if(recent.message==WM_USER+1) break;
            TranslateMessage(&recent);
            DispatchMessage(&recent);
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    tWnd();
    return 0;
}
```

This code never gets WM_TIMER message.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

class tWnd {
private:
    static LRESULT CALLBACK Disp_test_WndProc(
        HWND hwnd,        // handle to window
        UINT uMsg,        // message identifier
        WPARAM wParam,    // first message parameter
        LPARAM lParam)    // second message parameter
    {
        switch (uMsg) 
        {
            case WM_TIMER:{
                printf("timer\n");

                return 0;
            }

            case WM_DESTROY: 
                return 0; 

            case WM_HOTKEY:{

            } return 0;
            // 
            // Process other messages. 
            // 
            default: 
                return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam); 
        } 
        return 0; 
    }

public:     
    tWnd() {

            WNDCLASSA wc;
            wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW; 
            wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC) Disp_test_WndProc; 
            wc.cbClsExtra = 0; 
            wc.cbWndExtra = 0; 
            wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL); 
            wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION); 
            wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW); 
            wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) NULL; 
            wc.lpszMenuName =  ""; 
            wc.lpszClassName = "Test"; 

            if (!RegisterClass(&wc)) 
               return; //cannot register window class



        HWND testingWindow = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST,"Test","topmost",WS_VISIBLE,0,0,200,200,0,0,0,0);

        SetTimer(testingWindow,101,500,(TIMERPROC)NULL);

        MSG recent;
        BOOL result;
        while((result=GetMessage(&recent,testingWindow,0,0))&&result!=-1) { //bool can be -1 in MS world
            if(recent.message==WM_USER+1) break;
            TranslateMessage(&recent);
            DispatchMessage(&recent);
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    tWnd();
    return 0;
}
```

This code gets WM_TIMER messages just fine.

The only difference between the two is that WM_PAINT message is default-processed in second variant. How come that having WM_PAINT handled prevents program from receiving WM_TIMER messages? How can I work around that?

I am using MingW w64 (GCC 5.3.0) if that matters.

Comment: Please post the code in the question, not off-site.

Comment: @MikeNakis done

Comment: I do not know why this is happening, but I would not be surprised if Windows detects that you are a) not allowing default handling of the WM_PAINT message and b) not doing any actual painting yourself so it thinks that your app may be busy with something, so it better not disturb it with timer messages.  Whatever, this is highly non-standard, I would not worry too much about it.

Comment: @MikeNakis this bullshit has caused a lot of worry to me. Yes I am doing actual repainting in other version of this program.

Comment: @MikeNakis I would be grateful even for a workaround.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A window receives a `WM_PAINT` message when its invalid region is non-empty. This is called out in the documentation for [`ValidateRect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145194.aspx):

> The system continues to generate [**WM_PAINT**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145213.aspx) messages until the current update region is validated.

A standard `WM_PAINT` handler validates the invalid region (e.g. by calling [`BeginPaint()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183362.aspx)), which the default implementation does. Simply returning `0` will not validate the window, and it continues to receive `WM_PAINT` messages.

`WM_TIMER` messages are lower priority than `WM_PAINT` messages.  Your window procedure never sees a timer message because it is constantly busy ignoring paint messages.  This is called out in the documentation for [`WM_TIMER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644902.aspx):

> The `WM_TIMER` message is a low-priority message. The [`GetMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936.aspx) and [`PeekMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644943.aspx) functions post this message only when no other higher-priority messages are in the thread's message queue.

Comment: What should a valid WM_PAINT processing have then? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145194%28v=vs.85%29.aspx - this one?

Comment: @EuriPinhollow: It needs to validate the invalid region. It usually does so by calling `BeginPaint`, and then painting the invalid portion. If you don't have any painting to do, you could also call `ValidateRect`.